# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React component looks like below, where I have defined the statusStyle object outside the React class; On a first test, I ensure passwords do not match, the code has no problem changing from color:green to red; on the second attempt (still with passwords not matching), the Browser page crashes with the error in the title... Why ? and where is the read only property ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

let statusStyle = {
  fontSize  : '20px',
  color     : 'green', //default to green, change accordingly
}

class ChangePwd extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            oldPwd        : '', 
            newPwd        : '',   
            confirmNewPwd : '',

            inProgress    : false, 
            statusText    : '',
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        //etc...
    }



    //wired up in the html.form onSubmit event;
    formSubmit_Handler = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ 
            inProgress   : true, //show spinner etc...
            statusText  : ''
        });

        if (this.state.newPwd != this.state.confirmNewPwd) {
            statusStyle.color = 'red'; //*** THIS WORKS FIRST TIME, SECOND TIME IT ERRORS *** wtf ?

            this.setState({
                statusText  : 'The passwords you entered did not match.',
                inProgress   : false, //hide spinner etc...
            })

            return false; //bypass server-side call...
        }

        //continue to server-side call... 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <etc></etc>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sohail, just like i have shown in the question, above the Component/Class definition.

Comment: Where are you consuming this data from your ```statusStyle``` object? I suspect the problem is there. If you are setting a component prop to this object, you are probably trying to directly edit it by reference, which is not allowed. Either way, this is not a good way to store data. Since this variable exists outside of the component, React will not re-render accordingly when the value changes. Even if it works in one instance, you will soon run into problems as you've seen. Create a flag in your state and use that to control the color.

Comment: @ChrisB, i am consuming it within the render return section, inside a div <div style={statusStyle}>{this.state.statusText}</div>, where I show green/red Text; I could easily declare it as two constants of green or red, did not feel it warrants being part of the state. Somehow React has decided to transform my variable to a read-only property AFTER the first use, i.e. one change is allowed, thereafter no more changes - that's the part I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editing the existing object:

> statusStyle.color = 'red';

I am now creating a new object, based on the previous:

> statusStyle = {...statusStyle, color:'red'};

and the error is gone.

(I guess that is just the way React works, it does not like you to update an external object ?)

Answer (score 2):

Why to update external objects?
If any data that needs to be updated, you should be using 'state' for that.
Just think... if you can do this mutation to an external object, you will never need 'state'.
So....it works  when you spread prev Object and then change its property but its not good practice.

```
this.state = {
   ...restState,
   statusStyle : {
      color : 'red'
   }
}
```

and then whenver you want it to be updated, use..

```
this.setState((prevState) =>(
   {
     ...prevState,
     statusStyle : {
        ...prevState.statusStyle,
        color : 'blue'
     }
   }
))
```

(considered best practise as per documentation... go through below link)

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Why to update external objects? I'll tell you why, because that object is just a style object, it is not part of the core logic of my component.. i don't want to clutter my component's state with other cr*p, Lol